# Responisve layout for a div containing 3 images intersecting

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to make the Content div responsive,
the div is composed of two images on in the left and the other in the right,
 and in the middle of the there is an image, part of the middle image will be in the left and another part will be in the right image,

I want when the screen resizes whole of those images to be sized accordingly,

this is a link,
http://syrdoccam.com/oleaotel/

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="topHead">
                <div class="container clearfix">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div style="height: 500px;">
            <!--<div id="pic1"> </div>--><img src="img/pic1.png" class="pic1" >
            <div class="reservation"></div>
        <!--<div id="pic2"></div>--><img src="img/pic2.png" class="pic2" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">

    </div>
</div>


.content {
    border-top: 1px solid #EEF0EF;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 2px #DFE1DF;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 95;
}

.reservation {
    background: url("../img/reservation.png") no-repeat scroll;
    float: left;
    height: 74%;
    left: 33%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 26%;
    width: 52%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this.

```
<div class="content">
  <img class="left">
  <div class="detail"></div>
  <img class="right">
</div>
```

**Style**

```
.content {
  position:relative;
}

.content .left, .content .right, .content .detail {
  position:absolute;

  top:0;
  z-index:1;
}

.content .left {
  left:0;
}

.content .right {
  right:0;
}

/** For Click-able dive**/
.content .detail {
  z-index:2;
  left:25%; /** Putt how much u want **/
}
```

Comment: #Jey Theva 
this helped a lot but didn't solve it completely, I am working now on resizing the images when the screen resizes

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in multiple ways you can either style the images width and height in percentages. that way any adjustment in browser size automatically affects the images. try adding the code to your css

```
img.pic1 {
width:30%
float:left;
}


img.pic2 {
width:30%
float:right;
}

.clear {
clear:both;
```